# How can I generate a unique dom id for a html tag from model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, helper

I am having an index view with several rows for items which have multiple attributes. I would like to update the content of an items attribute with ajax, therefore I need a unique dom id. Is there a helper method available?
What I am doing right now is:

```
<span id="<%=  item.id.to_s + "_on_storage"%>">
```

Best,
Phil

Answer (score 22):

You can use

```
dom_id(item)
```

Which is an ActiveRecord method for generating DOM IDs.

Comment: dom_id is the helper that I am looking for. But what do I have to do when I want to have a dom id for each attribute in the model? e.g dom_id(item.attribute_in_the_model)

Comment: You can use "#{dom_id(item)}_attribute_name". I do suggest you use classes for attributes though, not ID, since class repeats itself and it is very comfortable to have them in classes. Then you can get the object by $("#item_343 .attribute_name") . Very clean, very intuitive.

Comment: Also if you want full wrapper tags with id and class set matching for a record you can use the gem [record_tag_helper](https://github.com/rails/record_tag_helper).

Answer (score 4):

A good practice as well is to use HTML5 data attributes:

```
<span data-item-id="<%= item.id %>">
```