# Set id of dynamically created autocomplete_field

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get an dynamically created `autocomplete_field` to work.

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
 new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
 id = new_object.object_id
 fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
  render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
 end
 button_tag(name, type:"button", class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

I use this method to create:

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :user_name ,  autocomplete_user_name_games_path ,:id_element=>"#my_user_id" %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, id: "my_user_id"%>
```

As I will create many autocomplete_fields I need a unique id for every autocomplete and hidden_field pair. But if I use something like `SecureRandom.hex` every id is the same because the first helper method is populated once and so the `SecureRandom.hex` is always the same.

Comment: check out dom_id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817398/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-dom-id-for-a-html-tag-from-model